# Another word for "carrying pole"?

Tags: single-word-requests

My sister-in-law wrote in her memoirs that while she and her sister were scavenging for food and water in a burned-out town in Germany during the war, they found and used a *pede*, which she described in terms that made it clearly a carrying pole, like this:

[image]

I have not been able to find the word *pede*, either in German or English.  Perhaps, since she was originally from East Prussia, it was an Old Prussian word?  Or some other language?  I am really perplexed, and my SiL is no help; she doesn't remember the word, either.  But there it is.

**Edited to Add**: Now that I've accepted an answer ("Yoke"), I've continued to investigate the matter, and it now appears that the word may be [Low Prussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Prussian): "It developed on a Baltic substrate through the influx of Dutch and Low German speaking immigrants."  This notion is especially attractive because my sister-in-law seems to have picked up the word during her residence in the burned-out town of [Preussisch Holland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paslek) (or Prussian Holland), a town which was specifically settled by immigrants from Holland in the 13th Century.

Comment: Are you looking for a confirmation that the word 'pede' really exists?

Comment: @Josh61: Not confirmation.  I am trying to find out if the word, or some form of it, actually exists, or if it does not, is there actually a single word that corresponds to "carrying pole"?

Comment: I think 'yoke' is used to indicate a carrying pole.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrying_pole *yoke* is used to name the pole/bar which carries the two loads. It's also called *a shoulder pole* and *a milkmaid's yoke*.

Comment: Yoke: A frame designed to be carried across a person's shoulders with equal loads suspended from each end.
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Yoke

Comment: If "yoke" is the answer, this is a general reference question. Other than that, there is "pinto" in Mandarin.

Comment: @ermanen, it might now be a general reference question, but it didn't start out that way.  The word at question, *pede*, was either a very rare or antique English word that might only be found in older dictionaries, or is an obscure foreign word.  I am now leaning towards the possibility that it is an Old Prussian word.  Not many dictionaries of that out there.

Comment: A tangent to the question, but note that to an Indo-Europeanist, [Old Prussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Prussian) means an extinct language closely related to Latvian and Lithuanian. I'm not sure whether you mean this, or mean to refer to an older German dialect.

Comment: Hi @ColinFine, I'm not thinking in terms of anything older than Old Prussian, which I do know was a Baltic language (interestingly, my wife's maiden name is Baltuttis).  My wife's family lived where she was in a position to pick up both Old Prussian and Low Prussian words.  Old Prussian died out as a living language three hundred years ago while Low Prussian (actually a German dialect) is still in use although not so much in Germany now).  Some OP words may have survived in local use, and LP words as well, although I haven't been able to locate dictionaries for either.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @Cyberherbalist. I didn't mean "older-than-Old-Prussian" German dialects, I just wasn't sure whether you knew about Old Prussian. I wasn't aware that any OP words had survived into (German) Prussian.

Comment: @ColinFine, this is a subject of great interest to me, and delightfully tangential!  In that spirit I note that the Wikipedia article on Old Prussian this text occurs: "The regional dialect of Low German spoken in Prussia (or East Prussia), Low Prussian, preserved a number of Baltic Prussian words, such as *kurp*, from the Old Prussian *kurpi*, for shoe (in contrast to the standard German *Schuh*)." My wife's family was in a position to have been able to pick up a number of such old OP words.

Comment: That picture is not a yoke. A yoke whether for people or cattle, always has a roundy bit for the neck. That picture shows a pole that requires two people. One on each end. What is the matter with everybody?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English word for this is "yoke". It is not very common today, as the object it refers to is not common in developed countries today.

**Edit**: definition 3.a from the OED:

> A frame fitted to the neck and shoulders of a person for carrying a pair of pails, baskets, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is the word, the OP is looking for. I'm sure he's well aware of its meaning and use. I associate a yoke with cattle, or with a strong man ploughing the field alone, not with a bar or pole.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: that is one meaning of it. I also associate it with a milkmaid carrying two pails of milk. (Hmm. That's the only context in which I would say _pail_ rather than _bucket_).

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Colin is right, this is a correct word for it, I am simply hoping that *pede* is also a word for it.  My sister-in-law was very deliberate about the word, I don't know where she came up with it (and neither does she, now; age has taken its toll), but it just *feels* right to me.  I am probably nuts.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist   If the entry was handwritten, it's probably a transcription error, if the loop is less than circular  it could look like an -e, and joined up to the -l might make it look like a -d ?

Comment: No, @Mari-LouA, what I have was typewritten.  She wrote the book back in 1980, and if there were a transcription error, she made it herself -- I don't know if she first wrote it in longhand, but she definitely transcribed it herself if she did.

Comment: The picture does not contain a yoke. Two people are required to carry the baskets with that pole. A  yoke has a roundy bit for the neck and is a one-dog act ....Colin, you really surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

The term “lecticarerum” is a neologism from the Latin “lectica rerum”, referring to a two-person carrying pole.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).